# Planning to install Office web apps 2010 SP1 with sharepoint 2010 environment, I would like to know what is the impact and how to troubleshoot?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

Planning to install Office web apps 2010 SP1 with SharePoint 2010 environment, I would like to know what is the impact and how to troubleshoot?

please suggest me as soon as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are issues that you may experience when you install these service packs:
•   SharePoint Server 2010 SP1 has an issue that causes workflow tasks to become locked and unrecoverable, as follows. Assume that you have a running out-of-box (OOB) workflow task (for example, an "Approval – SharePoint 2010," "Collect Feedback – SharePoint 2010," or "Publishing Approval" task). When a task assignee edits the workflow task (for example, by approving or rejecting the trial), the task is locked and cannot be recovered. For more information about this issue, click the following article number to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
2737435 "In Progress" Workflow tasks are locked after updating to SharePoint 2010 SP1

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2532126/known-issues-when-you-install-office-2010-sp1-and-sharepoint-2010-sp1